# After compilation the same program gives different answers

Tags: c

I've made a code that divides 2 numbers in any system from 2-70 with the symbols given in main. For some reason after compiling I am getting a lot of different answers, even tho the major part of them is correct. Can you maybe help me with that?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *symb; // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d

int convto10(int sys, char *num)
{
    int ans=0;
    int count=0;
    int sysdeg=1;
    while(*num!='\0' && *num!=EOF)
    {
        num++;
        count++;
    }
    num--;
    for(int j=0; j<count; j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<sys; i++)
        {
            if(*num==symb[i])
            {
                ans=ans+sysdeg*i;
                sysdeg*=sys;
            }
        }
        num--;
    }
    return ans;
}

char *convtosys(int sys, int num)
{
    char *ans;
    int temp=num;
    int count=0;
    while(temp>=sys)
    {
        count++;
        temp/=sys;
    }
    ans=malloc(count+1);
    ans+=count;
    while(num>=sys)
    {
        temp=num%sys;
        num=num/sys;
        *ans=symb[temp];
        ans--;
    }
    *ans=symb[num];
    return ans;
}

char *minusn(int sys, char *f, char *s)
{
    char *minus;
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    int c=0;
    char ch;
    while(*f!='\0' && *s!='\0')
    {
        f++;
        s++;
        count1++;
    }
    if(*f!='\0')
    {
        ch='f';
        while(*f!='\0')
        {
            f++;
            count2++;
        }
    }
    else if(*s!='\0')
    {
        ch='s';
        while(*s!='\0')
        {
            s++;
            count2++;
        }
    }
    f--;
    s--;
    if(ch=='s')
    {
        char *temp=f;
        f=s;
        s=temp;
    }
    int count=count1+count2;
    minus=malloc(count+1);
    minus+=count;
    char *e;
    char *d;
    e=malloc(1);
    d=malloc(1);
    for(int i=0; i<count1; i++)
    {
        *e=*f;
        *d=*s;
        int a=convto10(sys, e);
        int b=convto10(sys, d);
        a-=c;
        if(b>a)
        {
            a+=sys;
            c=1;
        }
        int temp=a-b;
        char *stemp=convtosys(sys, temp);
        *minus=*stemp;
        minus--;
        f--;
        s--;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<count2; i++)
    {
        *e=*f;
        int a=convto10(sys, e);
        if(i==0)
        {
            if(c==1)
            {
                a-=c;
            }
        }
        char *stemp=convtosys(sys, a);
        *minus=*stemp;
        minus--;
        f--;
    }
    minus++;
    if(*minus=='0')
    {
        while(*minus=='0' && *(minus+1)!='\0')
        {
            minus++;
        }
    }
    if(ch=='s')
    {
        minus--;
        *minus='-';
    }
    return minus;
}

char *multn(int sys, char *f, char s)
{
    char *mult;
    int b=convto10(sys, &s);
    int count=0;
    int c=0;
    while(*f!='\0' && *f!=EOF)
    {
        f++;
        count++;
    }
    f--;
    mult=malloc(count+1);
    mult+=count;
    char *e;
    e=malloc(1);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        *e=*f;
        int a=convto10(sys, e);
        int temp=a*b+c;
        char *stemp=convtosys(sys, temp);
        if(*(stemp+1)=='\0')
        {
            c=0;
            *mult=*stemp;
        }
        else
        {
            stemp++;
            *mult=*stemp;
            *stemp='\0';
            stemp--;
            c=convto10(sys, stemp);
        }
        mult--;
        f--;
    }
    if(c==0)
    {
        mult++;
    }
    else
    {
        *mult=*convtosys(sys, c);
    }
    return mult;
}

char *sumn(int sys, char *f, char *s)
{
    char *sum;
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    int c=0;
    char ch;
    while(*f!='\0' && *f!=EOF && *s!='\0' && *s!=EOF)
    {
        f++;
        s++;
        count1++;
    }
    if(*f!='\0' && *f!=EOF)
    {
        ch='f';
        while(*f!='\0' && *f!=EOF)
        {
            f++;
            count2++;
        }
    }
    else if(*s!='\0' && *s!=EOF)
    {
        ch='s';
        while(*s!='\0' && *s!=EOF)
        {
            s++;
            count2++;
        }
    }
    f--;
    s--;
    int count=count1+count2;
    sum=malloc(count+1);
    sum+=count;
    char *e;
    char *d;
    e=malloc(1);
    d=malloc(1);
    for(int i=0; i<count1; i++)
    {
        *e=*f;
        *d=*s;
        int a=convto10(sys, e);
        int b=convto10(sys, d);
        int temp=a+b+c;
        char *stemp=convtosys(sys, temp);
        if(*(stemp+1)=='\0')
        {
            c=0;
        }
        else
        {
            stemp++;
            c=1;
        }
        *sum=*stemp;
        sum--;
        f--;
        s--;
    }
    if(ch=='f')
    {
        for(int i=0; i<count2; i++)
        {
            *e=*f;
            int a=convto10(sys, e);
            int temp=a+c;
            char *stemp=convtosys(sys, temp);
            if(*(stemp+1)=='\0')
            {
                c=0;
            }
            else
            {
                stemp++;
                c=1;
            }
            *sum=*stemp;
            sum--;
            f--;
        }
    }
    else if(ch=='s')
    {
        for(int i=0; i<count2; i++)
        {
            *d=*s;
            int b=convto10(sys, d);
            int temp=b+c;
            char *stemp=convtosys(sys, temp);
            if(*(stemp+1)=='\0')
            {
                c=0;
            }
            else
            {
                stemp++;
                c=1;
            }
            *sum=*stemp;
            sum--;
            s--;
        }
    }
    if(c==1)
    {
        *sum='1';
    }
    else
    {
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}

char *multf(int sys, char *f, char *s)
{
    char *mult;
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    while(*f!='\0' && *f!=EOF)
    {
        f++;
        count1++;
    }
    f-=count1;
    while(*s!='\0' && *s!=EOF)
    {
        s++;
        count2++;
    }
    s--;
    int count=count1+count2;
    char e;
    for(int i=0; i<count2; i++)
    {
        int tc=0;
        e=*s;
        s--;
        char *temp=multn(sys, f, e);
        int len=(int)sizeof(temp);
        char *temp1=malloc(len+i);
        while(*temp!='\0')
        {
            *temp1=*temp;
            temp++;
            temp1++;
            tc++;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            *temp1='0';
            temp1++;
            tc++;
        }
        temp1-=tc;
        mult=sumn(sys, mult, temp1);
    }
    int ch=0;
    while(ch==0)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<sys; i++)
        {
            if(*mult==symb[i])
            {
                ch=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        mult++;
    }
    mult--;
    return mult;
}

int comp(int sys, char *f, char *s)
{
    int len1=0;
    int len2=0;
    while(*f!='\0')
    {
        f++;
        len1++;
    }
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        s++;
        len2++;
    }
    if(len1>len2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(len2>len1)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        f-=len1;
        s-=len2;
        for(int i=0; i<len1; i++)
        {
            int j1, j2;
            for(int j=0; j<sys; j++)
            {
                if(*f==symb[j])
                {
                    j1=j;
                }
                if(*s==symb[j])
                {
                    j2=j;
                }
            }
            if(j1>j2)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(j2>j1)
            {
                return 2;
            }
            f++;
            s++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

char *dividef(int sys, char *f, char *s)
{
    char *rem=NULL;
    int len1=0;
    int len=0;
    int count=0;
    char *ans;
    while(*f!='\0')
    {
        f++;
        len1++;
    }
    f-=len1;
    ans=malloc(len1);
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        s++;
        len++;
    }
    if(len>len1)
    {
        *ans='0';
        ans++;
        *ans='\0';
        ans--;
        return ans;
    }
    s-=len;
    rem=malloc(1);
    *rem='0';
    while(*f!='\0')
    {
        int cmp;
        int tempc=0;
        char *temp;
        temp=malloc(len+2);
        while(*rem!='\0')
        {
            *temp=*rem;
            temp++;
            rem++;
            tempc++;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<(len-tempc); i++)
        {
            *temp=*f;
            temp++;
            f++;
            if(*f=='\0' && i<(len-tempc-1))
            {
                return ans;
            }
        }
        temp-=len;
        cmp=comp(sys, temp, s);
        if(cmp==2)
        {
            if(*f=='\0')
            {
                return ans;
            }
            temp+=len;
            *temp=*f;
            f++;
            temp-=len;
        }
        cmp=comp(sys, temp, s);
        if(cmp==2)
        {
            if(*f=='\0')
            {
                return ans;
            }
            temp+=(len+1);
            *temp=*f;
            f++;
            temp-=(len+1);
        }
        printf("%s ", temp);
        if(*temp=='0')
        {
            while(*temp=='0')
            {
                temp++;
            }
        }
        int i=1;
        char *mtemp;
        printf("%c %d ", symb[i], cmp);
        cmp=2;
        while(cmp==2 && i<sys)
        {
            mtemp=multn(sys, s, symb[i]);
            cmp=comp(sys, mtemp, temp);
            printf("| %c %s %s %d", symb[i], mtemp, temp, cmp);
            i++;
        }
        if(cmp==1)
        {
            i-=2;
        }
        else if(i==sys)
        {
            i-=1;
        }
        mtemp=multn(sys, s, symb[i]);
        *ans=symb[i];
        ans++;
        count++;
        rem=minusn(sys, temp, mtemp);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    ans-=(count-1);
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    symb=malloc(16);
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        if(i>=0 && i<=9)
        {
            symb[i]='0'+i;
        }
        else if(i>9 && i<=35)
        {
            symb[i]='a'+i-10;
        }
        else if(i>35 && i<=61)
        {
            symb[i]='A'+i-36;
        }
        else
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 62: symb[i]='!'; break;
                case 63: symb[i]='@'; break;
                case 64: symb[i]='#'; break;
                case 65: symb[i]='$'; break;
                case 66: symb[i]='%'; break;
                case 67: symb[i]='^'; break;
                case 68: symb[i]='&'; break;
                case 69: symb[i]='*'; break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
    char *first="ab547";
    char *second="b78";
    char *ans=dividef(16, first, second);
    printf("%s\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

The right answer would be "ef", but beside I am getting a lot of different answers. First I thought the problem was the compare function, which I changed. Now I am getting the right answer more frequently, but still there are wrong answers printed.

Comment: Non-deterministic behavior is usually a sign of incorrect memory management.  Use your compiler or operating system's tools for detecting such issues.  For example using `gcc -fsanitize=address` indicates a buffer overflow in your program: https://godbolt.org/z/aYsKn19nc

Comment: @Delev1n For example this code snippet  ans=malloc(count+1);
    ans+=count; does not make a sense and leads to undefined behavior in this statement *ans=symb[temp];.

Comment: This code is very hard to read. You manually do a lot of extra work that could be done with separate functions which increases the likelihood of making a mistake. Specifically, you manually increase `char *` until you find the length, then only fix the original pointer if you need to work with it. I'm not sure if this was an attempt at manual optimization, but the compiler is very good at inlining/rearranging functions so you will not see a noticeable performance increase from this. Please either use `strlen(x)` or make your own string length function for this project.

Comment: @Locke The problem is that I am not allowed to use anything. I need to do everything manually. But will it really help if I just make a function that does the same and call it from there? If yes, I will do that, but it will still only do worse for my pointers. What are the other ways to count the length of a string without calling a function?

Comment: In this line `mult=sumn(sys, mult, temp1);` `mult` seems to be uninitialized pointer. Make sure to initialize variables. Compile with max warning enabled. Do use functions to cleanup the code.

Comment: Instead of this wall of code, please post a [mcve] or at least the part of the code containing the problem. If you are getting compiler messages then copy/paste those here and also let us know which line they are pointing at.

Comment: @Delev1n I would recommend making your own string length function even if it doesn't seem to be a problem at the moment. Separating out that functionality will help by reducing the number of places an error occurred due to a small mistake and make your existing functions a bit more verbose. Plus, if you are submitting this as an assignment you want to make your code as easy to read as possible for a grader.

Comment: Raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and correct your source until all errors and warnings are gone. -- Refactor logical steps into functions. A good size of a function is less than a screenful, so it can be grasped without scrolling. -- Use a consistent code style, more whitespace, longer variable names, optimally adopt a commony style. -- `EOF` commonly cannot be represented as a `char`. Why do you compare to it? What use case do you have in mind that you have this character in a string?

Comment: @Delev1n "*What are the other ways to count the length of a string without calling a function?*" What is the problem with functions ?